# Grails scaffolding does show nothing

Tags: java, grails, groovy, scaffolding

I use grails 2.4.4

I added dependenci in my BuildConfig:

```
dependencies {
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2"
}
```

and add plugin:

```
plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
}
```

Create domain Person:

```
package person

class Person {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String name
}
```

And controller:

```
package person

class PersonController {

    static scaffold = Person
}
```

Also try to use: static scaffold = true, it also doesn't work. I try to delete my package target.

But in my url (http://localhost:8090/grails-com.learning/person) I see nothing

[image]

There is no the plugin:

[image]

Comment: Is `grails-com.learning` the name of the application?

Comment: Yeas it is)))))))))

Comment: I dont't see scafolding plugin in my plugins

Comment: "I dont't see scafolding plugin in my plugins" - If you mean in the `plugins{}` block of your `BuildConfig.groovy`, it is indeed in the code you showed.  `compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/adamscaffolding.

[grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L49-L75](https://github.com/jeffbrown/adamscaffolding/blob/a506c6420fcc8927ebcc77d5b944b3cef7b07c48/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy#L49-L75)

(there is no need to mention the scaffolding plugin in the `dependencies {}` block, the `plugins {}` block is where to express that)

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
    // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
    //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
    //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
    //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
    //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
}
```

[grails-app/domain/person/Person.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/adamscaffolding/blob/a506c6420fcc8927ebcc77d5b944b3cef7b07c48/grails-app/domain/person/Person.groovy)

```
package person

class Person {

    static constraints = {
    }

    String name
}
```

[grails-app/controllers/person/PersonController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/adamscaffolding/blob/a506c6420fcc8927ebcc77d5b944b3cef7b07c48/grails-app/controllers/person/PersonController.groovy)

```
package person

class PersonController {

    static scaffold = Person 

}
```

That scaffolding behaves as intended.

Comment: I have already tryed to use scaffolding withot dependencies, it is also doesn't work(

Comment: "I have already tryed to use scaffolding withot dependencies, it is also doesn't work" - The scaffolding plugin definitely works in Grails 2 without expressing a dependency on in it in the `dependencies` block.  In Grails 2 the way to express that dependency is in the `plugins{}` block of `BuildConfig.groovy`.  With Grails 3 and later, a different syntax would be used and it would be in `build.gradle`, but for a Grails 2.4.4 project, `compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"` in the `plugins{}` block of `BuildConfig.groovy` is what you want.

Comment: If you can share a project similar to the one that I created for you, but demonstrates the problem you are talking about, I will be happy to send you a PR to fix it or describe whatever is wrong.

Comment: Thanks you already have helped to me enough, problem was in my settings. If you realy interesing you can see my learning project https://github.com/AlexandarVysotskiy/grails-learning branch LESSON-4

Comment: Earlier you said the app name was `grails-com.learning`.  That project is called `grails-learning`.  Is the 404 because you are sending the request to the wrong url?

Comment: No, url is valid, problem was in my setting, there was no scaffolding in my plagings.